# Display content based on URL string

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here's the scenario, upon successfully installing our software, we launch your web browser and display a thank you page.

I'm trying to figure out how to display an additional block of html that notifies the user if they've just installed an older version and provides a download link to the latest.

Upon install, an older version would display something like this:
www.oursite.com/thanks/?v=2.2.0

While the current version should generate something like this
www.oursite.com/thanks/?v=3.0.0.20932

(They both bring you to the same page, just have a different token)

I've considered adding redirects to our .htaccess -but we've released many incremental versions and that could get messy quick.

We're running wordpress - so php or js should work fine, i just don't have the programming chops for something like this and don't even know where to begin.

Comment: @Xeon06 has the simplest solution. There's no need include .htaccess. If they're visiting your site, store the latest version in a database, query the latest version number, then compare the `$_GET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply compare the version string with a "latest version" constant that you would update manually.

```
<?php
    define(LATEST_VERSION, "3.0.0.20932");

    if ($_GET['v'] != LATEST_VERSION)
        echo "<p>You don't have the latest version.</p>";
?>
```

Comment: If I have helped you, please consider clicking the green checkmark to the left of my post to accept my answer as the solution to your problem.